# allocate a new memory for matrix

Tags: c++, memory-management, matrix

I have two classes:

```
class A

class B: class A
```

I want to create a matrix that each pointer point to B (mat of 1X2).

so I defined:

```
A **mat;

mat = new A*[1];
*mat = new B[2]; // call the constructor.
```

now I have 2 elements: mat[0][0], mat[0][1].

mat[0][0] is initialized but mat[0][1] is NULL.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sizeof(A) < sizeof(B)` than an array of `A`'s is not equivalent to an array of `B`'s.
Since in the second allocation you allocate *concreete objects* which are larger than what `*mat` is supposed to point to, when you access the second element it doesn't access the second `B` element, but rather slices into the first.

That's my guess anyway, since you didn't tell us much about `A` and `B`.

**EDIT**

To answer your comment, I'd start by limiting the amount of raw pointers you use. Use a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of vectors instead. Each element of the vector can be a raw pointer to an `A`. Which can have a run-time type of `B` or `C`.

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::vector<A*> > mat(1, std::vector<A*>(2, (A*)0));
```

Comment: thank you, but if I have: class B: public A.. and class C: public A.. and I want to create a matrix that each cell can be B or C, how can I do it? thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you need pointers to B, you don't need to specify anything about A. Since B derives A, you only have to allocate space for the larger one (B in this case).

For a matrix of pointers, you will need the following.

```
B *** mat;
mat = new B**[1]; //Dimension 1 
mat[0] = new B*[2]; //Dimension 2 (array of pointers)
mat[0][0] = new B(); //Allocate B in [0][0]
mat[0][1] = new B(); //Allocate B in [0][1]
```

But if you know it will always be 1x2, just use the following:

```
B * mat[1][2];
```

Comment: thank you, but if I have: class B: public A.. and class C: public A.. and I want to create a matrix that each cell can be B or C, how can I do it? thank you!

Comment: You can create another class D: public B, public C. Then your matrix can be of type D*. When you read from the matrix you can cast to B or C easily. However, when writing B or C to the matrix, you will manually have to cast to type D. Another option could be to use a matrix of void* pointers and cast them to different pointers, but this would be dangerous.